# NameError:Function not defined

Tags: python

I have a class RelayChannel and I want to call the function RelayChannelOn() to this code but I get error : `NameError: name 'RelayChannelOn' is not defined`.

Here is the code where am calling the function.

```
  import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

    import time
    import RelayChannel



    #Relay=RelayChannel()


    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)



    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN) #PIR

    GPIO.setup(RelayChannelOn(13), GPIO.OUT) #BUzzer



    try:

        time.sleep(2) # to stabilize sensor

        while True:

            if GPIO.input(21):

                GPIO.output(RelayChannel(13), True)

                time.sleep(0.5) #Buzzer turns on for 0.5 sec

                GPIO.output(RelayChannel(13), False)

                print("Motion Detected...")

                time.sleep(5) #to avoid multiple detection

            time.sleep(0.1) #loop delay, should be less than detection delay



    except:

        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: This appears to be a general Python question.  Perhaps search for a Python tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a period in the following line:

```
GPIO.setup(RelayChannelOn(13), GPIO.OUT) #BUzzer
```

change it to:

```
GPIO.setup(RelayChannel.On(13), GPIO.OUT) #BUzzer
```